# string from istringstream getline not comparing right

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I am reading a text file, then comparing the first line of the file, which is "abc", to a string that is "abc" and they are not evaluating to equal, although my log statement is showing that they are the same. (it's outputting abc!=abc)

What I noticed is, if I make my text file only one line then it evaluates that they are equal.

I've tried things such as using strcmp or the compare function but i get the same results.  I've also tried making my string I am comparing to "abc\n" and that didn't work either.

Here is my code:

```
string testString = FileUtils::getInstance()->getStringFromFile("test.txt");
istringstream ss(testString);
string s;
string s2 = "abc";

getline(ss, s, '\n');

if(s == s2){
    CCLOG("%s","we are good...");
}
else{
    CCLOG("%s!=%s", s.c_str(), s2.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `'\n'`? I could imagine that the current formulation of the code reads the entire file (or fails to compile).

Comment: yeah, sorry, my code had \n not /n

Comment: Is it possible that the text contains an "invisible" character, e.g., a `'\r'`? You may want to print the size of the read strings and print the characters individually using a numeric value for each or, at least, for the non-graphical characters.

Comment: Thank you Dietmar!! That was it, there was an '\r' there.  I didn't know about '\r'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that strings my contain "invisible" characters. Notably, some systems represent end of lines using a line end sequence, e.g., a `"\r\n"` sequence. If that is the case, the string may look as the same but also contain a carriage return. You can check it printing the string like so:

```
std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

If there is a carriage return you'd get something like

```
97 98 99 13
```

The somewhat confusing aspect is that you said the output you see is

```
abc=abc
```

I would expect it to be

```
=abc
```

as the output would be

```
abc\r=abc
```

and the `'\r'` should reposition the cursor at the start of the line. Unless your `CCLOG()` ends up removing carriage return characters.